# Installing/Configuring Zend Debugger for Eclipse PDT

Tags: apache2, php, eclipse, webserver, zend

I`m unable to configure in IDE or install properly Zend debugger.

- Installed php5.6 libapache2-mod-php5.6 and so on.

  Downloaded Zend debugger for php5.6 separate from other zend stuff. (It last available separate from zend studio, thats why I choose php5.6)

  Copy dummy.php to document root, check in browser it works(empty page without errors)

  Add following to php.ini: 

    `$ tail -n 10 /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini 
    [Zend]
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/ZendDebugger.so"
    zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16
    zend_debugger.expose_remotely=1
    zend_debugger.connector_port=10137`

Do configure debugger in eclipse>Window>PHP>Servers>Localhost>Edit:

[local server configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPqCn.png)

[debugger settings for server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwBLu.png)

[global debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a6wM.png)

**Error occurred**: [click on test button in debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR0Sd.png)

**Error occurred**: [return to global debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBsUM.png)

Try to debug: 
[click on debug as>php web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzpRt.png)

*What I`m doing wrong? Reading a lot of pages, all give similar instructions as above. Please help.*

Also posting phpinfo() screenshot, all seems fine there:
 - [zend debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFpG0.png)
 - [zend modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83JhV.png)

**UPDATE:** I found a solution, for thus who interested read the post bellow. Site does`t accept it as answer yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Zend Debugger** installed from separate bundle not working with **PHP5.6**. Problem in Zend opcache module. Seems they loaded in incorrect order.

Disabling zend opcache makes the solutions. Debugger work fine. But it possible to make work both this way:

Comment out it in config: (cli version seems to be symlink as also disabled)

`lenya@JabbaDesktop:~$ sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini`

```
; configuration for php opcache module
; priority=10
; zend_extension=opcache.so
```

At bottom of /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/opcache.so"
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/ZendDebugger.so"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=1
zend_debugger.connector_port=10137
```

First two lines(.so) should be exactly in this order.
Installing debugger "how to" easy to find in google. No one mention above problem.